# Delete duplicate element from sorted linkedlist using recursion in java

Tags: java

I want to use recursion to remove the duplicate element from sorted linkedlist. Can anyone please help me out

```
public void removeDuplicates(Node head) { 

    Node temp = head; 
    while (temp.next != null) { 
        if (temp.data.equals(temp.next.data)) { 
            Node next_next = temp.next.next; 
            temp.next = null; 
           temp.next = next_next; 
        } else { 
            temp = temp.next; 
        } 
    } 
    new LinkedListStack().iterateLinkedList(head); 
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have solution using while loop, need solution using recursion 
    public void removeDuplicates(Node head) {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            if (temp.data.equals(temp.next.data)) {
                Node next_next = temp.next.next;
                temp.next = null;
                temp.next = next_next;
            } else {
                temp = temp.next;
            }

        }
        new LinkedListStack().iterateLinkedList(head);
        return;
    }

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) If you want to provide details to your question, please use the `edit` function to add them to your question.

Comment: And your problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
public ListNode removeDuplicateElements(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (head.data.equals(head.next.data)) {
        ListNode next_next = head.next.next;
        head.next = null;
        head.next = next_next;
        removeDuplicateElements(head);
    } else {
        removeDuplicateElements(head.next);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code. maybe this could help.

```
public class MySortedLinkedList
{
    /* nested class Node
     *
     * stores a single item in the linked list
     */
    public class Node
    {
        public Comparable item;
        public Node next;

        public Node(Comparable i)
        {
            item = i;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    // a reference to the first node in the list
    private Node head;
    // a reference to the node to return when next() is called
    private Node iterator;

    /* constructor
    * creates a linked list with no items in it
    */
    public MySortedLinkedList()
    { 
        head = null; 
        iterator = null;
    }

    /* isEmpty
     * inputs: none
     * return value: returns true if there are no items in linked list
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    { return (head == null); }

    /* add
     * inputs: Comparable item
     * return value: none
     * adds an item into the list in sorted order
     */
/*
    public void add(Comparable item)
    {
        // make the new node to insert into list
        Node newNode = new Node(item);
        // first see if the list is empty
        if (head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("add "+item +" to front");
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }
        // there is something in the list
        // now check to see if it belongs in front
        else if (item.compareTo(head.item) < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("add "+item +"before"+head.item);
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        // otherwise, step down the list.  n will stop 
        // at the node after the new node, and trailer will
        // stop at the node before the new node
        else
        {
            Node after = head.next;
            Node before = head;
            while (after != null)
            {
                if (item.compareTo(after.item) < 0)
                    break;
                before = after;
                after = after.next;
            }
            // insert between before & after
            newNode.next = before.next;
            before.next = newNode;
            System.out.println("add "+item +"after"+before.item);
        }

    }
*/

    // TODO: implement recursive add
    public void add(Comparable item)
    {
        System.out.println("Recursive add not yet implemented");
    }

    /* contains
     * inputs: Comparable item
     * return value: true if equal item is in list, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean contains(Comparable item)
    {
        Node n = head;
        // for each node in the linked list
        while (n != null)
        {
            // if it is equal, return true
            // note that I used compareTo here, not equals
            // because I am only guaranteed that the 
            // compareTo method is implemented, not equals
            if (item.compareTo(n.item) == 0)
                return true;
            n = n.next;
        }
        // if it is not found in list, return false
        return false;
    }

    /* toString
     * inputs: none
     * return value: string representation of the linked list items
     * Format must match assignment
     */
/*
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(100);
        Node n = head;
        // for each node in the linked list
        while (n != null)
        {
            s.append(n.item.toString());
            n = n.next;
        }
        // if it is not found in list, return false
        return s.toString();
    }
*/
    // TODO: Write this recursively!!
    public String toString()
    {
        System.out.println("Recursive toString not yet implemented");
        return null;
    }

    /* next
     * inputs: none
     * return value: one element from the linked list 
     * This method returns each element in the linked list in order.
     * It is to be used in a loop to access every item in the list.
     */
    public Comparable next()
    {
        if (iterator != null)
        {
            Node n = iterator;
            iterator = iterator.next;
            return n.item;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    /* reset
     * inputs: none
     * return value: none
     * resets the iterator so that the next call to next() will
     * return the first element in the list
     */ 
    public void reset()
    {
        iterator = head;
    }

    // TODO: implement recursive size
    /* size
     * inputs: none
     * return value: the number of elements in linked list
     */
    public int size()
    {
        System.out.println("Recursive size not yet implemented");
        return 0;
    }

} // end of public class MySortedLinkedList
```